# Why my custom posts aren't showing in my local WordPress website?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm learning WordPress. I'm in the way to learn "How to create and show custom post in WP". I'm using a plugin call "Custom Post Types UI". Via this plugin I add the new custom post called Project Feature with the post_type project_feature. Ot has a title, a thumbnail and a description area.

In my php file I wrote the following codes to display this:

```
                    <?php
                        $loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'project_feature', 'orderby' => 'post_id', 'order' => 'ASC'));
                    ?>
                    <?php
                        while($loop->have_post()):$loop->the_post();
                    ?>

                    <div class="col-sm-4">


                    <?php
                        if(has_post_thumbnail())
                        {
                            the_post_thumbnail();
                        }
                    ?>
                        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                        <p class="black_text"><?php the_content(); ?></p>
                    </div>  <!-- col  -->  



                    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

But this isn't working. Can you please help me to understand what the wrong I am doing?

Thanks in Advance... :-)

Comment: Unfortunately, "It doesn't work" doesn't give any information about the problem. Do you have any error message ? Can you see your data in your `wp_posts` table ?

Comment: I recommand to use ACF to manage custome post type. Their documentation is easy to understand and will be able to display your cpt in few minutes.

Comment: No. I don't see any error message.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have done all correct but in

```
$loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'project_feature', 'orderby' => 'post_id', 'oider' => 'ASC'));

'oider' => 'ASC' might be 'order' => 'ASC'
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction. But it still don't show any custom post.

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'project_feature',
    'orderby' => 'post_id',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);
/* print $query and see in what parameters are you getting data, eg., i got data in post_title */
while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
    $thisisid = get_post($post->ID);
    echo  $thisisid->post_title;
endwhile;
```